Can someone help me find a USB, device, casing, whatever for an AX210 Intel Wireless card?
I want to plug it into a USB slot instead of, whatever. Looking for a device that can, yeah.

Ask your question here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ But add much more detailed list of requirements

The AX210 chipset is specifically designed to connect via PCIe, not USB. Thunderbolt can carry PCIe signals, but USB cannot. So if you have a port with a USB Type-C connector that's actually a Thunderbolt port, you could buy an external PCIe slot chassis box that connects via Thunderbolt, and put a PCIe AX210 card in that. That's the closest you'll get to what you're trying to do.
